# How to import range in google spreadsheet ignoring the Error "overwrite data"?

Tags: import, google-sheets, importerror, array-formulas

[image]

In above picture I have the  following formula `importrange("spreadsheet_id","Sheet!A2:P1010")` in cell  `A2767`

I have some data below now is there any way to ignore that error and let it fetch and overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importrange needs blank cells to hold the size of the content you are importing. If the example you gave is in column A then "A67:P1077" need to be cleared. You can have data in the sheet after that for those rows and columns. You can force that to happen with

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("importtosheetname");// replace with your   sheet name
  var values = sheet.getRange("A68:P1077").getValues(); //note that the formula cell is not deleted assuned to be A67
  if (values[0][0] == "#REF!")
  sheet.getRange("A67:P1077").clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me :)